# Add background color to DT rows in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have some code that creates a DT table with radio buttons. On top of that I need to add particular colors to each row. I have been trying to use formatStyle too add a different color to each row but I haven't gotten the syntax correct.

Here is the working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

c1 = "This is comment 1"
c2 = "This is comment 2"
c3 = "This is comment 3"
c4 = "This is comment 4"
c5 = "This is comment 5"
comments1 = list(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)


m1 = matrix(
 as.character(1:5), nrow = 5, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE,
 dimnames = list(comments1, LETTERS[1])
)
for (i in seq_len(ncol(m1))) {
 m1[, i] = sprintf(
   '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
   'AValue', m1[,i]
 )
}

callback1 <- c(
 "var LETTERS = ['AValue'];",
 "for(var i=0; i < LETTERS.length; ++i){",
 "  var L = LETTERS[i];",
 "  $('input[name=' + L + ']').on('click', function(){",
 "    var name = $(this).attr('name');",
 "    var value = $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked').val();",
 "    Shiny.setInputValue(name, value);",
 "  });",
 "}"
)



ui <- fluidPage(
   title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
   DT::dataTableOutput('foo1'),
   verbatimTextOutput('sel1'),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$foo1 = DT::renderDataTable(
     m1, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
     options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
     callback = JS(callback1),
   ) 

   output$sel1 = renderPrint({ 
     input[["AValue"]]
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here are the **some** of the different variations of the calls that I have tried.

```
#formatStyle needs to be called on DT:datatable() 
    #Test adding formatStyle
    output$foo1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      dat <- datatable(m1, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', 
        options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE))
      callback = JS(callback1)  %>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(3,'red'))
    })
```

or

```
    #Test adding formatStyle
    output$foo1 <- DT::renderDataTable({    
      DT::datatable(m1,escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', 
        options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, callback = JS(callback1))
        %>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(3,'red')))
    })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the table as an argument of the `formatStyle`. To do that inside the `renderDataTable` you can use the `datatable` function.

It seems that your condition to assign a color to a row is not going to match any row. You need to put something that could be in the column. Below is an example where an entire row has a red background when the content in column 0 is equal to `"This is comment 3"`.

```R
  output$foo1 = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      m1, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS(callback1)
    ) %>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual('This is comment 3','red'))
    }, server = FALSE
  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to daisy chain formatStyles together to add color to multiple rows such as:  ```%>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(3,'red'))
                          %>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(2,'yellow'))```

Comment: Try `%>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(2, 3), c('yellow','red')))`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can define a new column with row_numbers and assign colors to the rows of interest.  You can make the `row_num` column not visible.  Try this

```
mycolors <- c('green','pink','red','yellow','orange')
  output$foo1 = DT::renderDataTable({
    m2 <- as.data.frame(m1) %>% dplyr::mutate(row_num = 1:n())
    
    datatable( m2, escape = FALSE, 
               selection = 'none', 
               extensions = c("Select", "Buttons"), 
               callback = JS(callback1),  ###   needs double-click to select the radiobutton
               options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                              columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=2))
                              )
               )   %>% formatStyle(2, 
                                   target='row',
                                   backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1:5),mycolors))
      
    }, server = FALSE,
    #callback = JS(callback1)  ###  does not recognize input[["AValue"]]
  )
```

[image: output]

Comment: I get an error on the n() function inside mutate. Is that defined somewhere else?

Comment: I set it to the number of rows 5. ```row_num=1:5``` and it seems to work

Comment: `n()` is from `dplyr` package.  Please try `?n()` in your RStudio console.